react-bootstrap form-control type date initial value not shown
I am using react-bootstrap and set one of the form-control to type="date", but the initial date value is not shown, instead it shown the date format.
This is what I have:
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

return <Form.Control type="date" value={moment(startDate).format("D-MM-YYYY")} onChange=((e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)) />

This should show the date of now as initial value. But it doesn't, when I look at the source code it shows the value correctly, but somehow the placeholder or so shows the format instead.
I did try to set the placeholder with the same value, but nothing happened.
Am I missing anything?

You can try using this YYYY-MM-DD or this format DD-MM-YYYY, I am not sure if this is the problem but your format just doesn't look right to me.

I think there are two primary issues to address to get this working the way you expect. (both draw from this mdn reference for input fields)

Input fields with type="date" expect a value attribute to be provided as a string formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD", but your current format doesn't match this.

State initialization should be consistent with state updates. The onChange function providing e.target.value is going to put a string formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD" in startDate state. That's exactly what we need for #1, so you just need to initialize state like that too. (Right now, your initialization is putting a Date type object in startDate.)


If you need the format shown in your question, then you'll need to look further into localization of input fields for the browser environment(s) you are working on I think.
code sandbox example
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Form, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./App.css";

function nowFormatted() {
  const nowDate = new Date();
  let mm = nowDate.getMonth() + 1; //zero indexed month
  mm = mm > 9 ? mm : "0" + mm; //zero pad month
  let dd = nowDate.getDate();
  dd = dd > 9 ? dd : "0" + dd; //zero pad day
  return nowDate.getFullYear() + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
}

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(nowFormatted);

  function handleInputChange(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "my-date") {
      setStartDate(e.target.value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form>
        <Form.Control
          id="my-date"
          type="date"
          value={startDate}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}

